# Multiple image thumbnail viewer

Tags: c#, thumbnails, image, preview

I am trying to create a simple winform application in c# that can load multiple images from a file dialog into the application screen. I am using ListView control to contain those images as picture box control wasn't going to serve my needs as I want to be able to select loaded thumbnails and do many other things based on the selection.

The problem I am having is to do with **thumbnail image quality.**
Once they get loaded in the application window panel, the image quality is very poor.
I want them to look just like how Windows operating system displays preview/thumbnails of images in large icon with a decent image quality.

I've tried adding this `listView1.LargeImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;` as suggested by other people but it won't even let the app load images.

Here is the code done so far.

```
using (OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    open.Title = "Open Image";
    open.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    open.Multiselect = true;

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ImageList picList = new ImageList();
        listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        picList.ImageSize = new Size(200, 130);

        foreach (String file in open.FileNames)
        {
            Image i = Image.FromFile(file);
            Image pic = i.GetThumbnailImage(200, 130, null, new IntPtr());
            picList.Images.Add(pic);
        }

        listView1.LargeImageList = picList;
        listView1.LargeImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;


        for (int i = 0; i < picList.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = i;
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I should do to make it just as good as 
Windows' default thumbnail viewer?

Comment: what is the original size of the images you are loading? it could be that 200x130 is too big of a reduction

Comment: You said you tried the PictureBox. Did you look into the Zoom functionality of it? I'm not sure what else you're trying to do with the objects, but you could assign the file to the Tag property of the element (both PictureBox or ListViewItem).

Comment: Original image can be at any size and I want to make it generate a fixed size of thumbnails from any variable sized originals.

Comment: It must enable thumbnail image selection(multiple) within the application and as far as I know PictureBox, by default, does not support that. It needs to delete/change display orders of the selected thumbnails and such so selecting behavior is important.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20013/Image-Thumbnail-Viewer-with-NET